# How to allow None value to be accepted in dataframe in Spark 2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a schema something like -

```
val schema = StructType( Seq (
StructField( "a", StringType, true),
StructField( "b", StringType, true),
StructField( "c", StringType, true)
))

and making a dataframe like - 

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val listrow: List[Row] = List(Row("E-001", "P-001", None), Row("E-001", "P-001", "Attending"))
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(listrow)
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, scm)
```

Now, when I do a df.first(), I get an error, the essence of which is - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding:   java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.None$ is not a valid external type for schema of string

Note that I need to create the df this way only. The above is just an example but the code in production is a bit complex. I think it used to work in Spark 1.6 but started to fail in Spark 2.0.1. Is this something to do with Encoders? Note that some of the data will always have None and the df needs to handle it. Is there a way to handle this or the data just cannot have None?

Can anyone else here too seen this and probably know what the solution is?

Thanking in anticipation!

Comment: Your column requires strings but `None` is not a string.  Convert the None to a string or change the column to accept `Option[String]` instead of `String` and convert your strings to `Option[String]`s.  Really, I'd want to fix the code that's producing those `None`s in the first place, That seems like a major design flaw.

Comment: I agree. But is there something that can be done with the schema to accommodate this?

Comment: What do you want the data to look like in the dataframe?  Do you literally want Different types (Option and String) sitting in the same column or do you want to be able to insert both types and have them be automatically homogenized to a single type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the None with null.asInstanceOf[String]:

```
val listrow: List[Row] = List(Row("E-001", "P-001", null.asInstanceOf[String]), Row("E-001", "P-001", "Attending"))

scala> df.show
+-----+-----+---------+
|    a|    b|        c|
+-----+-----+---------+
|E-001|P-001|     null|
|E-001|P-001|Attending|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

Or go with what was mentioned before and use a case class that uses Option[String] for that 3rd value:

```
case class Foo(a: String, b:String, c:Option[String])

val listFoo: List[Foo] = List(Foo("E-001", "P-001", None), Foo("E-001", "P-001", Some("Attending")))
listFoo.toDF.show
+-----+-----+---------+
|    a|    b|        c|
+-----+-----+---------+
|E-001|P-001|     null|
|E-001|P-001|Attending|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as I mentioned, I am looking to do something with the schema to accommodate such data changes, if what I am asking is possible.

Comment: Modifying the data before entering it into the dataframe is far more preferable.  You could use an Any type instead of StringType, if you really wanted to have Options and Strings in the same column.

Comment: Is there a type called Any for DataType?

Comment: If this worked in 1.6 I'm sure is because it was being mapped to String somehow and not because the column type was Any. Can you do a printSchema on that DataFrame on 1.6 and see its type?